# hide a dynamically created element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting data through ajax.I have an array holding all the data.Now I am running a loop through the array and dynamically creating a 'p' and a 'button' corresponding to each element of the array.If I click the button the innerHTML of corresponding 'p' should be passed to ajax and the button must disappear.Here is the sample of what i tried:

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<foo.length;i++)
{
     addElement(foo[i],i);
}
function addElement(foo,i)
{
    ni=document.getElementById("asdf");
    new_but=document.createElement('input');
    new_p=document.createElement('p');
    new_p.id='text'+toString(i);
    new_p.innerHTML=foo;
    new_but.type='button';
    new_but.value='add';
    new_but.id=toString(i);
    new_but.className='but';
    ni.appendChild(new_p);
    ni.appendChild(new_but);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.but').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              data:'awdwad',
              url:'aadwewq.php',
              success:function(result)
              {
                  if(result==no_error)
                  $(this).hide();
              }
});});});});
</script>
```

The elements are created but I am unable to access  them later using their ids or classes with jquery.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the right value back? result==no_error means that the data from ajax = result and no_error is another variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the `click` handler is being assigned onload, when the `.but` element does not exist. You need to delegate the click handler to the parent element like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#asdf').on('click', '.but', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:'awdwad',
            url:'aadwewq.php',
            success:function(result) {
                if (result == no_error)
                    $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, you can shorten your `addElement` function using jQuery like this:

```
function addElement(foo, i) {
    var $ni = $('#asdf');
    var $p = $('<p></p>', { 'id', 'text' + toString(i) }).html(foo).appendTo($ni);
    var $button = $('<input></input>', {
        'type': 'button',
        'id': toString(i),
        'class': 'but'
    }).appendTo($ni);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding brackets `{}` to the `if`, also. Not necessary, but goot practice.

Comment: Thanks i got it right.I was having prob as to assigning the click handler

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on` and attach event on some parent object or document. Also there is no need to iterate over objects.

```
$(document).on("click", ".but", function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside your `success` callback of your `$.ajax` call refers to the ajax call itself. 
You should make a reference to the button first.

With the feedback of the other answers combined:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.but', function() {
       var btn = $(this);
       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           data:'awdwad',
           url:'aadwewq.php',
           success:function(result)
           {
               if(result==no_error)
               $(btn).hide();
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addElement(foo,i){
    ni=document.getElementById("asdf");
    new_but=document.createElement('input');
    new_p=document.createElement('p');
    new_p.id='text'+i; //remove toString
    new_p.innerHTML=foo;
    new_but.type='button';
    new_but.value='add';
    new_but.id=i;  // remove toString
    new_but.className='but';
    ni.appendChild(new_p);
    ni.appendChild(new_but);
}
```

Comment: Also as ThiCE suggested, get the reference of the btn clicked so that it can be accessed by success function. Check this url http://jsfiddle.net/UC5gb/2/

Comment: currently tested with error function, since ajax call fails in my test